# warning: Insecure world writable dir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, warnings, ubuntu-10.04

After installing Rails accord to this post [Ubuntu, Ruby, RVM, Rails, and You](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/).

At using `scaffold` I see some strange warnings.

I followed next steps:

```
nazar@desktop:~/Documents/rails⟫ rails new blog
nazar@desktop:~/Documents/rails/blog⟫ cd blog
nazar@desktop:~/Documents/rails/blog⟫ rails generate scaffold post title:string body:text
/home/nazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/nazar in PATH, mode 040777
/home/nazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/nazar in PATH, mode 040777
/home/nazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/bundler-1.6.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/nazar in PATH, mode 040777
/home/nazar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/spring-1.1.2/lib/spring/application.rb:164: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/nazar in PATH, mode 040777
```

I wondering to know if I understand right `rails` uses SqlLite by default?
Coz at `blog/db` it didn't create any `sqlite3` file?

***Is something wrong here?***

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a warning that your home directory is writeable to by anyone in your group plus anyone else at all (i.e. world).  The `777` at the end of the mode is indicating the directory is writable by all of yourself (owner), the group plus world.  Normally it should end with `755` or `750` depending on how open you want your home directory to be.

It is not going to stop anything working but it's a legitimate warning as you really don't want your home directory open like this.

Easiest way to fix it is to execute command such as:

```
chmod go-w /home/nazar
```

which will remove write permission for group and others (world).